# How to print a binary search tree in level order, including the null values

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So right now, when I have a tree that looks like:

```
       5
         \
          6
           \
            7
             \
              9
```

I can print this in level order so that

```
5, 
6, 
7, 
9,
```

this is printed

However, I want to make it so that it prints something like this:

```
5,
0, 6,
0, 0, 0, 7,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9,
```

So that all the NULL nodes are also printed as 0.

```
void current_height(tree *root, int level){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if(level == 1){
        printf("%d, ", root->data);
    }
    else if(level > 1){
        current_height(root->left, level - 1);
        current_height(root->right, level - 1);
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far

BTW, I also thought about putting an index into struct tree so that I could change the tree into an array and just print the array.
But I found that it would make the deleting function too complicated so I didn't use that idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to simulate tree content which is not there.
Since you have the info on the relative target level as your additional parameter already in place that is not hard.
Just invent more tree nodes in case of NULL pointers before the target depth, always giving NULL as invented pointer.

```
void current_height(tree *root, int level){
    if(root == NULL){
        if (level>1){
            current_height(NULL, level - 1);
            current_height(NULL, level - 1);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d, ", 0);
        }
        return;
    }
    if(level == 1){
        printf("%d, ", root->data);
    }
    else if(level > 1){
        current_height(root->left, level - 1);
        current_height(root->right, level - 1);
    }
}
```

Output here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler is:

```
5, 
0, 6, 
0, 0, 0, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9,
```

Comment: Thanks so much man, works like a real charm! Actually my first time posting a question and I didn't know I would get an answer so quickly, gotta use this more often I guess. Thanks again so much

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling `current_height` on each node (which traverses the whole subtree on that node), makes this algorithm inefficient.

You could use this idea:

- Create an array for storing the current level of nodes. Make sure it is has a size that can contain the bottom level.
- At index 0 store the root reference.
- Then iterate the levels:
- Print the data of the nodes that are currently in the array
- Replace each node with its two children -- or when the node was actually a `NULL`, put two `NULL` values in the array.
- To avoid that data is overwritten before it is read, iterate the array from the rightmost filled-in node backwards to index 0, and store the child nodes also from right to left. This way there is no overwriting of parents before they are read.

Here is an implementation:

```
void level_order(tree *root) {
    if (root == NULL) return; // Nothing to print
    int h = height(root) - 1;
    tree *level[1<<h]; // Allocate 2^h entries 
    level[0] = root;
    for (int depth = 0; depth <= h; depth++) {
        for (int j = (1<<depth) - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            tree *node = level[j];
            int isNode = node != NULL;
            printf("%d, ", isNode ? node->data : 0);
            if (depth < h) { // Collect children for next iteration
                level[2*j+1] = isNode ? node->left : NULL; 
                level[2*j] = isNode ? node->right : NULL; 
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note that your `height` function returns the number of levels in the tree. The standard definition of "height" is the length of the path from root to its furthest leaf, expressed in number of edges (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology)). So a tree with just one node has height 0, and an empty tree (`NULL`) has height -1. This is why the above code subtracts 1 from the value that the `height()` call returns.